# error: "No directive found with exportAs 'ngForm'"

Tags: angular, component

Buenas tardes al momento de ejecutar en Angular ng serve -o
Me arroja el siguiente mensaje de error, probé importando NgForm en app.module.ts pero el problema persistió, lo borre ya que me daba otros errores. Si alguien me da una mano le estaré agradecido.
Eh buscado y probado varias soluciones importando FormsModule,ReactiveFormsModul
tambien FormsModule pero ninguno me soluciono el problema.
El error es el siguiente:

Repito el mensaje para rellenar:
Buenas tardes al momento de ejecutar en Angular ng serve -o
Me arroja el siguiente mensaje de error, probé importando NgForm en app.module.ts pero el problema persistió, lo borre ya que me daba otros errores. Si alguien me da una mano le estaré agradecido.
Eh buscado y probado varias soluciones importando FormsModule,ReactiveFormsModul
tambien FormsModule pero ninguno me soluciono el problema.
El error es el siguiente:

```
Error: src/app/components/login/login.component.html:13:25 - error NG8003: No directive found with exportAs 'ngForm'.     

13               <form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onLogin()" novalidate>
                           ~~~~~~

  src/app/components/login/login.component.ts:9:16
    9   templateUrl: './login.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    Error occurs in the template of component LoginComponent.


Error: src/app/components/login/login.component.html:16:116 - error NG8002: Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'.

16                   <input type="email" id="nombreUsuario" name="nombreUsuario" class="form-control form-control-lg" [(ngModel)]="nombreUsuario" name="nombreUsuario" required />
                                                                                                                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/components/login/login.component.ts:9:16
    9   templateUrl: './login.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    Error occurs in the template of component LoginComponent.


Error: src/app/components/login/login.component.html:16:129 - error TS2322: Type 'Event' is not assignable to type 'string'.

16                   <input type="email" id="nombreUsuario" name="nombreUsuario" class="form-control form-control-lg" [(ngModel)]="nombreUsuario" name="nombreUsuario" required />
                                                                                                                          
         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


  src/app/components/login/login.component.ts:9:16
    9   templateUrl: './login.component.html',
```

---

---

Mi  codigo en app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './components/header/header.component';
import { LogoArgPComponent } from './components/logo-arg-p/logo-arg-p.component';
import { BannerComponent } from './components/banner/banner.component';
import { AcercaDeComponent } from './components/acerca-de/acerca-de.component';
import { LaboralComponent } from './components/laboral/laboral.component';
import { EstudiosComponent } from './components/estudios/estudios.component';
import { NgCircleProgressModule } from 'ng-circle-progress';
import { SkillComponent } from './components/skill/skill.component';
import { ProyectosComponent } from './components/proyectos/proyectos.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './components/footer/footer.component';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './components/login/login.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    LogoArgPComponent,
    BannerComponent,
    AcercaDeComponent,
    LaboralComponent,
    EstudiosComponent,
    SkillComponent,
    ProyectosComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    NgCircleProgressModule.forRoot({}),
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

---

---

el login.component.html

```
        <div class="mb-md-5 mt-md-4 pb-5">

          <h2 class="fw-bold mb-2 text-uppercase">Login</h2>
          <p class="text-white-50 mb-5">Por favor ingresa tu email y contraseña!</p>

          <form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onLogin()" novalidate>
            
            <div class="form-outline form-white mb-4">
              <input type="email" id="nombreUsuario" name="nombreUsuario" class="form-control form-control-lg" [(ngModel)]="nombreUsuario" name="nombreUsuario" required />
              <label class="form-label" for="typeEmailX">Usuario</label>
            </div>
   
            <div class="form-outline form-white mb-4">
              <input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="form-control form-control-lg" [(ngModel)]="password" name="password" required />
              <label class="form-label" for="typePasswordX">Contraseña</label>
            </div>

            <p class="small mb-5 pb-lg-2"><a class="text-white-50" href="#!">¿Olvidaste tu contraseña?</a></p>

            <button class="btn btn-outline-light btn-lg px-5" type="submit">Ingresar</button>
          </form>

        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hay que  reiniciar el servidor para ver este tipo de cambios en las importaciones
Las directivas que necesitamos para crear formularios basados ​​en plantillas son de Template-driven
la cual es el que estas usando
están en **FormsModule**
no en **ReactiveFormsModule**
entonces :

```
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
```

y agrégarlo a nuestro NgModule como una importación y eliminemos ReactiveFormsModule.
En este orden de importacion

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    //BrowserAnimationsModule ver comentario
    NgCircleProgressModule.forRoot({
    
      radius: 100,
      outerStrokeWidth: 16,
      innerStrokeWidth: 8,
      outerStrokeColor: "#78C000",
      innerStrokeColor: "#C7E596",
      animationDuration: 300
       })
      ],
```

luego en la vista

```
 <form #f="ngForm"> ... </form>
<pre>{{f.value | json}}</pre> 

<circle-progress
  [percent]="85"
  [radius]="100"
  [outerStrokeWidth]="16"
  [innerStrokeWidth]="8"
  [outerStrokeColor]="'#78C000'"
  [innerStrokeColor]="'#C7E596'"
  [animation]="true"
  [animationDuration]="300"
></circle-progress>
```

de acuerdo a la guia de uso de   [ng-circle-progress](https://openbase.com/js/ng-circle-progress) 
y el codigo que compartiste no veo porque necesitas BrowserAnimationsModule

Answer (score -1):

Solution https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yna0nt3XyCg

```
AppModule
add
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    (...your section...),
```